# Spark read partition columns showing up null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an issue when trying to read partitioned data with Spark.

If the data in the partitioned column is in a specific format, it will show up as null in the resulting dataframe.

For example :

```
case class Alpha(a: String, b:Int)
val ds1 = Seq(Alpha("2020-02-11_12h32m12s", 1), Alpha("2020-05-21_10h32m52s", 2), Alpha("2020-06-21_09h32m38s", 3)).toDS
ds1.show
    +--------------------+---+
    |                   a|  b|
    +--------------------+---+
    |2020-02-11_12h32m12s|  1|
    |2020-05-21_10h32m52s|  2|
    |2020-06-21_09h32m38s|  3|
    +--------------------+---+
ds1.write.partitionBy("a").parquet("test")
val ds2 = spark.read.parquet("test")
ds2.show
    +---+----+
    |  b|   a|
    +---+----+
    |  2|null|
    |  3|null|
    |  1|null|
    +---+----+
```

Do you have any idea how I could instead make that data show up as a String (or Timestamp).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to set the parameter `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled` to `false`.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")
```